# How to remove an item from button click in datagridview. And display sum in the textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a datagridview bounded to a `Bindinglist` from a shared class. I added a column button to the datagridview. The program has no coding error and can be run. But when I click on the remove button, it gave error saying :
`Current item cannot be removed from the list because there is no current item.`

I also have a textbox which should display the sum of the prices in the datagrid. But it doesn't work.

What I tried:
The form which contains the `datagridview`

```
    public partial class ShoppingCart : UserControl
    {
        public ShoppingCart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cartlist.DataSource = ProductData.Items;
        }
```

The button to `remove items` in the list: **[SOLVED]**

```
 private void cartlist_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //Remove Row on Remove Click
            if (cartlist.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Remove") 
            {
                //Pops up Yes/No Message Box
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Remove Item?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    productBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();//Remove Row if Yes is clicked
                 
            
            }

        }
```

And the `textbox` which is supposed to show the total of the prices in the datagrid: **[SOLVED]**

```
private void ShoppingCart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Show Total Price in the textbox
            TotalBox.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in cartlist.Rows
                               where row.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                               select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();

        }
```

And here it what my `datagrid` is bounded to:

```
public class Product
    {
        private string item;
        private decimal qty, price;

        public string Item
        {
            get => item;
            set { item = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public decimal Quantity
        {
            get => qty;
            set { qty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public decimal Price
        {
            get => price;
            set { price = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

}
```

and within it:

```
    public static class ProductData
    {
        public static BindingList<Product> Items { get; set; } = new BindingList<Product>();
    }
```

Finally the output:
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo0PC.png)

EDIT: I got the Remove button to work properly.
I simply changed `productBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();` to `cartlist.Rows.RemoveAt(cartlist.CurrentRow.Index);` 
Solution.

```
private void cartlist_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //Remove Row on Remove Click
            if (cartlist.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Remove") 
            {
                //Pops up Yes/No Message Box
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "Remove Item?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    cartlist.Rows.RemoveAt(cartlist.CurrentRow.Index);//Correction Here
                 
            
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why don't use extract the selected cell row index from the event's arguments? Then you could remove the item from your BindingList via index.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm completely new to this just letting you know.

Comment: just make sure that the row index is not negative: BindingList.Remove(e.RowIndex);

Comment: You bound `ProductData.Items` directly to `cartlist.DataSource`. What is `productBindingSource`?

Comment: `productBindingSource` is the datasource the datagridview is bounded to. Its the `public class Product` which I bound the datagrid to make the rows and column appear, cause when its just binded to `ProductData.Item`, it won't show the columns and rows in the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bound `ProductData.Items` directly to `DataGridView`.
Then use this collection everywhere.

```
private void Cartlist_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (cartlist.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Remove")
    {
        //if (MessageBox.Show ...
        ProductData.Items.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Calculate and show total.

```
private void ShoppingCart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TotalBox.Text = ProductData.Items.Sum(x => x.Price).ToString();
}
```

---

You probably need to show Total continuously updated.
Subscribe to BindingList event.

```
ProductData.Items.ListChanged += Items_ListChanged;
```

Here the same code as in Load event.

```
private void Items_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TotalBox.Text = ProductData.Items.Sum(x => x.Price).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I managed to find a similar solution for the remove button just as you posted.

Comment: @Blewbles - you can post you own answer (and accept it)

Comment: Nah, you're a lifesaver man. But the show total wouldn't show still though.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        _id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
        string _name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string _lname = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string _sex = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string _age = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["delete"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if(groupBox1.Visible==true)
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
            }
            _id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to delete?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK) && service.deleterecord(_id, _name, _lname, _age, _sex))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("deleted record");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show("not deleted");
            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["edit"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
            firstname.Text = _name;
            lastname.Text = _lname;
            gender.Text = _sex;
            age.Text = _age;
        }
    }**Please try this will get the index of cell and delete it or edit just for additional**
```